# Alguien sabe porque el break no funciona

Tags: javascript, condiciones, while

Tengo un problema, el `break` no está haciendo efecto. La idea es que el usuario elija entre "si" y "no". Si elije "si" le saldrá otro `prompt` con los distintos productos. La idea es que si el usuario elije "no" se corte lo demás. Se supone que el `break` es para eso pero no funciona y continua leyendo el código que no debería leer. Lo que yo quiero es que el usuario cuando escriba "no", ya no corra más el código y que cuando escriba "si", que aparezcan los otros prompt de los demas juegos para que elija cuantos quiere de cada uno.

```
                let opcion

do{
    opcion = prompt(" ¿Desea comprar algun producto? , si es asi escriba (si) sino escriba (no) " )
    if (opcion != "si" && opcion != "SI" && opcion != "Sí" && opcion != "NO" && opcion != "No" && opcion != "no") {
        alert(" No pusiste lo especificado ")
    }else{
        if (opcion == "si" || opcion == "SI" || opcion == "Si" ) {
            opcion = opcion
        }if (opcion == "NO" || opcion == "No" || opcion == "no") 
            alert(" Usted decidio no comprar ")
            break;
    }
}while (opcion != "si" && opcion != "SI" && opcion != "Sí" && opcion != "NO" && opcion != "No" && opcion != "no")




do{ 
    cantidadproducto1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de COD quiere llevarse"))
    cantidadproducto2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de Fifa 23 quiere llevarse"))
    cantidadproducto3 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de Lego Marvel quiere llevarse"))
    cantidadproducto4 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de UFC 4 quiere levarse"))
    cantidadproducto5 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de The Last of Us quiere llevarse"))
    cantidadproducto6 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de R6 quiere llevarse"))
    cantidadproducto7 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de R6 quiere llevarse"))
    cantidadproducto8 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de R6 quiere llevarse"))
    cantidadproducto9 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de R6 quiere llevarse"))
}while (cantidadproducto1 == 0 && cantidadproducto2 == 0 && cantidadproducto3 == 0 && cantidadproducto4 == 0 && cantidadproducto5 == 0 && cantidadproducto6 == 0) {
    if(cantidadproducto1 == 0 && cantidadproducto2 == 0 && cantidadproducto3 == 0 && cantidadproducto4 == 0 && cantidadproducto5 == 0 && cantidadproducto6 == 0){
        alert(" No selecciono ningun articulo ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Buen día, ejecuté tu código con "si" y con "no", en ninguno de los dos casos continua haciendo cosas, no es muy claro cual es el problema, ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar lo que sucede cuando escribes "si" y cuando escribes "no" así como lo que deseas que suceda?

Comment: Por otra parte, el `break` finaliza la ejecución de la instrucción `do` , `for` , `switch` o `while` más próxima que la incluya, no es para detener todo el código, en tu caso finalizaría la ejecución del `do`.

Comment: Ahi lo cambie, deberia funcionar ahora

Comment: Y como puedo hacer para que cuando escriba "no" todo el codigo se termine?

Comment: Sí, veo que agregaste más código pero aún no es claro ni el problema ni lo que deseas que suceda. Por cierto, cuando la pregunta contiene código `HTML`, `JavaScript` o `CSS` puedes utilizar un fragmento de código interactivo (Séptimo botón o Ctrl + M).

Comment: En general no hay forma de que se "termine" el código, tendrías que generar un error, lo mejor sería usar una función como lo puse en la respuesta.

Comment: Si usaras funciones tendrías más control sobre la ejecución del código. `break` solo termina el bucle actual. `return` para la ejecución de la función y sale de ella.

Comment: Buen día @Agustin, si alguna respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Cuando deseas que una sección de código se ejecute únicamente en determinados momentos es mejor crear una función y llamar a la función cuando se necesite ejecutar dicha sección de código.

Por ejemplo, podrías crear una función `catalogo` para mostrar todos los `alert` únicamente cuando el usuario escriba "si".

Por cierto, como pudiste darte cuenta, el usuario puede ingresar múltiples combinaciónes de "si" y "no", para no tener que escribir todas las combinaciones (Que por cierto te hace falta considerar si "sí" lleva tilde o si  escribe "sI") puedes procesar la entrada del usuario y convertirla siempre a minúsculas y remover las tildes.

Para remover las tildes puedes utilizar [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize):

```
opcion.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
```

Esta línea elimina los diacríticos y convierte las letras a su valor normalizado, por ejemplo `íóü` se convertiría en `iou`.

Luego puedes convertir la opción a minúsculas para no trabajar con tantas combinaciones:

```
opcion.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "").toLowerCase()
```

Y para evaluar únicamente "si" y "no" puedes utilizar [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
['si', 'no'].includes(opcion.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "").toLowerCase())
```

Ahora, como necesitas que se repita cuando el usuario escriba algo diferente a "si" o "no" entonces negamos la sentencia enterior con `!`:

```
!['si', 'no'].includes(opcion.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "").toLowerCase())
```

Ejemplo completo:

```js
let opcion

// Función catalogo que se ejecutará únicamente al ser llamada
function catalogo() {
  // Como tenías muchas variables similares es mejor utilizar un arreglo
    productos = [];
    productos[0] = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de COD quiere llevarse")) || 0;
  productos[1] = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de Fifa 23 quiere llevarse")) || 0;
  productos[2] = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de Lego Marvel quiere llevarse")) || 0;
  productos[3] = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de UFC 4 quiere levarse")) || 0;
  productos[4] = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de The Last of Us quiere llevarse")) || 0;
  productos[5] = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cuantos juegos de R6 quiere llevarse")) || 0;
  
  // resultado contará los elementos del arreglo
  let resultado = productos.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
    });
  
  // Si el resultado de la suma de todos los elementos del arreglo productos es 0
  if (resultado == 0) {
    alert("No seleccionó ningun articulo ")
    return 0;
  }
  // En caso contrario, si la suma es cualquier valor diferente de 0
  else {
    alert(`Se seleccionaron ${resultado} artículos`)
    return productos;
  }
}

// La primera parte de tu código
do{
    // Obtenemos el valor de entrada del usuario, eliminamos diacríticos y convertimos a minúsculas
    opcion = prompt(" ¿Desea comprar algun producto? , si es asi escriba (si) sino escriba (no) " ).normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "").toLowerCase();
    
    if (!['si', 'no'].includes(opcion)) {
        alert(" No pusiste lo especificado ")
    }else{
        if (opcion == "si") {
            catalogo()
            break;
        }if (opcion == "no") 
            alert(" Usted decidio no comprar ")
            break;
    }
    // Como ya revisas que opción sea "si" o "no" adentro del while
    // No hace falta revisarlo aquí, con hacer un do -> while infinito es suficiente
}while (true)
```

### Edición

Gracias al comentario de @MarcePuente es importante mencionar que `/\p{Diacritic}/gu` está disponible a partir del 2021, si se utilizan versiones anteriores puedes utilizar `/[\u0300-\u036f]/g`.

También agregué `|| 0` al final de cada línea donde se obtiene el número de artículos, en caso de que el usuario oprima `Cancel` se generaba un `NaN` (Del inglés Not a Number) y el resultado del alert era `NaN`, ahora si hay algún `NaN` se cambiará por `0` gracias a la modificación.

Comment: Hola @HeytalePazguato, en principio tu código no se ejecuta, si cambias el texto de **replace** por **/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, ""**, funciona, además si realizas una compra de un producto y niegas las demás, te sale un mensaje tipo *has comprado NaN articulos, podrias editar tu respuesta?.

Comment: No se si he sido claro, si compra un producto, y en otro producto le da al botón cancelar (algo esperable), se produce el error.

Comment: @Marce no crees que es mejor idea [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/578478/edit) la respuesta corrigiendo el problema? Si Heytale no está de acuerdo puede revertir la edición o adaptarla.

Comment: Hola @Mateo, tal vez tengas razón, si fuera solo cambiar el texto del **replace**, lo hubiese hecho, pero como aparte tiene un problema más profundo, que implica un cambio que desde su idea, no se abordar, preferí avisarle para que lo corrija y subir mi propia implementación... no soy un gran programador... snif.

Comment: Gracias a ambos, voy despertando, lo reviso cuando tenga un tiempo en el trabajo. Por cierto, el texto del replace puede ser cualquiera de las dos pero tienes que ver la versión que usas, `Diacritic` puede ser utilizado a partir del 2021

Comment: @MarcePuente, Ya he agregado ` || 0` y corrige el problema del `NaN`. Lo demás no lo modifiqué ya que podría hacerse más eficiente o interrumpir el proceso de compra si el usuario oprime cancelar, pero para no hacer tantos cambios en el código del OP lo dejé así.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato, maestro, me nutro de sus respuestas, gracias!!

Comment: Hahaha, yo no me había dado cuenta de los problemas xD fue ayuda mutua. Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

aca dejo una opción, basada en la respuesta de @HeytalePazguato, adaptada a mi vagancia... espero que sea de utilidad.

```js
let opcion
let mensajes = [
  "Ingrese cuantos juegos de Fifa 23 quiere llevarse",
  "Ingrese cuantos juegos de Lego Marvel quiere llevarse",
  "Ingrese cuantos juegos de UFC 4 quiere levarse",
  "Ingrese cuantos juegos de The Last of Us quiere llevarse",
  "Ingrese cuantos juegos de R6 quiere llevarse"
]

function catalogo() {
    productos = [];      
    let resultado = 0;

    for( let i = 0; i < mensajes.length; i++ ) {
        productos[ i ] = parseInt( prompt( mensajes[ i ] ));
        if( ! isNaN( productos[ i ] )) {
            resultado += productos[ i ]
        } 
    }
 
    if( resultado == 0 ) {
        alert( "No seleccionó ningun articulo" )
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        alert( `Se seleccionaron ${resultado} artículos` )
        return productos;
    }
}

do {
    opcion = prompt( "¿Desea comprar algun producto?, si es así escriba \"si\", sino, escriba \"no\"" ).normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toLowerCase();
    
    if( ! [ 'si', 'no' ].includes( opcion )) {
        alert( "No pusiste lo especificado" )
    }
    else {
        if( opcion == "si" ) {
            catalogo()
            break;
        }
        else if( opcion == "no" ) {
            alert( "Usted decidio no comprar" )
            break;
        }
    }
} while( true )
```